# How do I get an opponent prone during a grapple?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, grapple, prone

When Grappling...

- If I successfully [Pin](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Pinned) my target would they be considered Prone for things that require that?
- Alternately, could I free action [Drop Prone](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Drop-Prone) bringing them with me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## A [pinned](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Pinned) creature isn't automatically also [prone](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Prone)

The condition [pinned](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Pinned) doesn't *say* that it also counts as the condition [prone](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Prone). Further, the description of the combat maneuver [grapple](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Grapple) doesn't indicate that a pinned creature is *either* rendered actually prone *or* considered virtually prone.

## A [grappling](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Grappled) creature that [drops prone](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Drop-Prone) doesn't render its [grappled](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Grappled) or [pinned](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Pinned) foe [prone](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Prone)

The free action [dropping prone](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Drop-Prone) says, "Dropping to a prone position in your space is a free action," but this does *not* mean it's, like, a move action to drop prone in *another* creature's space… or anything else. Dropping prone is typically something one creature opts to do alone. While it would be awesome for the grappling creature to be able to drop prone and pull down its grappled foe with it, because neither the description of the action [dropping prone](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Drop-Prone) nor of the combat maneuver [grapple](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Grapple) says anything about pulling down grappled foes by dropping prone, *only* the creature that takes the action dropping prone actually and for-reals drops prone.

But the grappling creature, while continuing its engagement with its grappled foe, *could* drop prone—nothing *stops* it—, yet its grappled foe will remain standing in its own space. Likewise, a grappled foe could opt to drop prone if, for some reason, it *wanted* to, but the creature grappling it will remain standing in its own space.

To be clear, when Creature A successfully [grapples](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Grapple) Creature B, next round Creature A typically has only three options: move, damage, and pin. If Creature A pins Creature B, Creature A adds to its options tying up Creature B. The damage option available to Creature A is *not* like a standard attack—it's an opposed grapple check that, if on which Creature A's successful, sees Creature A just deal damage appropriately—and the only *choice* usually available being whether to deal lethal damage or nonlethal damage. Creature A typically just *can't*, for example, make the combat maneuver trip *instead* of taking that damage option. And, unlike [in its predecessor *D&D 3.5e*](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/specialAttacks.html#grapple), Creature A in *Pathfinder* is typically forbidden from making attacks normally. (Creature B, however, is typically not quite so restricted in its actions.)

If Creature A's goal is to wrestle Creature B while Creature B's on the ground, then typically Creature A makes a successful combat maneuver [trip](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Trip) first to prone Creature B *then* makes the combat maneuver grapple then, next round, goes for the pin. And, the entire time, Creature A can opt to remain standing.

***Note:*** Weasel words permeate this answer because there are literally multiple exceptions to every part *of the grappling rules. This answer attempts to put forth the rules at their most basic. Please accept this writer's apology for overlooking your favorite exception.*

Answer (score 0):

When grappling there are many different conditions that can be applied to a character. Here are a few relevant to your questions.

- **Grappled :** You are basically holding the other character to prevent him from moving. That could be explained in game by you holding their arm/wrist or performing some sort of bear hug. The rules make no mention of being prone or not, so one is not required for the other to happen.
- **Pinned :** Your target is "tightly bound and can take few actions". While this could be explained in game by describing your character "pinning" his foe to the ground or to a wall, it could also be described as performing an arm lock or some other form of advanced grappling move, like modern-day judo or jujutsu. Again, nowhere in the rules does it refer to being prone, so RAW it seems that pinned and prone are different conditions.
- **Prone :** Your target "is lying on the ground". That's it! It doesn't have to be grappled, nor does it have to be prone as a consequence of grappling. Sometimes, people just fall.

What you want to do is perform the "**trip**" combat manoeuver.

> **[TRIP](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Trip)**
>
> You can attempt to trip your opponent in place of a melee attack. You can only trip an opponent who is no more than one size
>   category larger than you. If you do not have the Improved Trip feat,
>   or a similar ability, initiating a trip provokes an attack of
>   opportunity from the target of your maneuver.
>
> If your attack exceeds the target's CMD, the target is knocked prone.
>   If your attack fails by 10 or more, you are knocked prone instead. If
>   the target has more than two legs, add +2 to the DC of the combat
>   maneuver attack roll for each additional leg it has. Some
>   creatures—such as oozes, creatures without legs, and flying
>   creatures—cannot be tripped.

As you can see, you can perform a trip manoeuver instead of one of your normal attacks. You can still attack while grappling, so it's not impossible for you to perform this manoeuver while "hugging" your opponent.

In this case, if you want to grapple/pin a prone creature, you need to use one of your attacks to trip them first. Outside of special abilities that would let you knock prone your opponent for free (or at least grant a free trip attempt under certain conditions), it seems to be the normal way to bring someone to the ground.

As for dropping prone, the rules only cover dropping yourself prone. You can move your opponent during a grapple, but it seems that you really need to perform a trip manoeuver to actually get your opponent to the ground, you can't just bring him with you.

This does not mean that you can't actually flavor your trip/pin combo as a flying armbar :

1. Assuming you are already grappling, perform a trip manoeuver to bring your opponent down.
2. Upon success, use a free action to drop prone yourself.
3. Perform a pin manoeuver to hold him down.
4. Enjoy the glory of being a master martial artist (flying armbars aren't easy, yo!)

And that's it! If you want to make a career out of tripping people, I highly suggest the following feats :

- **Improved trip :** +2 to CMD against being tripped, no longer grants AoO for tripping others.
- **Greater trip :** grants you a AoO whenever you successfully trip an opponent, meaning that you don't "lose" one of your attacks for tripping your opponent (if you succeed, at least).
- **Tripping Strike :** grants you a free trip attempt upon scoring a critical hit

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer. I chose HICC's answer because I'm aware of the ability to Trip an opponent and was specifically looking to be able to have a target Prone and Grappled by a single character. Simply tripping allows them to optionally stand up before I could Grapple. I also believe he is correct that (unless there is a class feature or Feat I'm not aware of) you cannot perform other Maneuvers while Grappled.

Comment: @Ifusaso - Under the grappling rules, both characters are still allowed to make attacks, provided they can do so with only one hand. Trip is a combat maneuver that replaces an attack, and can easily be performed with your legs/feet as well as your one available hand. I don't see anything in the rules to suggest that you would need to release your opponent from the grapple before tripping him, as the 2 conditions are not mutually exclusive. Also, note that standing up is an action that provokes an attack of opportunity, which you could use to perform another trip maneuver and keep him down!

Comment: To play the devil's advocate, maintaining a grapple is typically a Standard action (Greater changes this to allow a Move grapple as well) that is not an attack action, therefore I cannot Trip with it as it's not one of the functions of successfully maintaining the grapple. Furthermore, you *cannot* successfully trip a person who is standing up using an attack of opportunity. http://www.d20pfsrd.com/extras/pathfinder-faq#TOC-Trip-3-15-11-

Comment: @Ifusaso - Oh damn, never saw that ruling in the FAQ. Good catch! But yeah, this "combo" relies on the fact that initiating a grapple does not use all of your round's attacks, so you can still perform the trip attack on the round you started the grapple, provided you have more than one attack available. For the rest, it mostly relies on AoO to go on, as you correctly pointed out the need to maintain the grapple.